# How can I connect to a Derby database using PHP?

Tags: php, derby

I am using an application that uses an embedded Derby database. I have no experience with this database type, I have previously used only MySQL and Oracle.

I need to insert some data to the Derby database via PHP.

How can I connect to a Derby database using PHP?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. In the past there used to be a freely available ODBC driver for the DRDA protocol used by the Derby Network Server, but AFAIK it is no longer available.